# get all followers with twitter

Tags: php, twitter

How can i get All my followers with one request?
If i do `$this->twitter->getFollowers();` 
I just get 100 of my followers;

An here is the code for getting followers

```
/**
     * Returns the authenticating user's followers.
     *
     * @return  array
     * @param   string[optional] $id     The id or screen name of the user for whom to request a list of followers.
     * @param   int[optional] $page
     */
    public function getFollowers($id = null, $page = null)
    {
        // build parameters
        $aParameters = array();
        if($page !== null) $aParameters['page'] = (int) $page;

        // build url
        $url = 'statuses/followers.xml';
        if($id !== null) $url = 'statuses/followers/'. urlencode($id) .'.xml';

        // do the call
        $response = $this->doCall($url, $aParameters, true, false);

        // convert into xml-object
        $xml = @simplexml_load_string($response);

        // validate
        if($xml == false) throw new TwitterException('invalid body');

        // init var
        $aUsers = array();

        // loop statuses
        foreach ($xml->user as $user) $aUsers[] = $this->userXMLToArray($user);

        // return
        return (array) $aUsers;
    }
```

Comment: see: http://www.cydeweys.com/blog/2009/03/10/a-python-script-to-auto-follow-all-twitter-followers/#comment-80827

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get all followers change API http://apiwiki.twitter.com/Twitter-REST-API-Method:-statuses%C2%A0followers

```
public function getMyContacts()
    {

    if (file_exists($this->getLogoutPath())) 
        {$auth=explode("/",file_get_contents($this->getLogoutPath()));$user=$auth[0];$pass=$auth[1];}
    else return false;
    $res=$this->get("http://{$user}:{$pass}@twitter.com/statuses/followers.xml",true);

    $cursorNext = array();
    $cursorNext[0] = -1;
    do {
    if($cursorNext[0] == -1 || $cursorNext[0] !=0)
    {
        $res = $this->get("http://{$user}:{$pass}@twitter.com/statuses/followers.xml?cursor={$cursorNext[0]}",true);

    } else {
        break;
    }

    if ($this->checkResponse('responce_ok_followers',$res))
        $this->updateDebugBuffer('responce_ok_followers',"http://user:pass@twitter.com/statuses/followers.xml?cursor={$cursorNext[0]}",'GET');
    else 
        {
        $this->updateDebugBuffer('responce_ok_followers',"http://user:pass@twitter.com/statuses/followers.xml?cursor={$cursorNext[0]}",'GET',false);
        $this->debugRequest();
        $this->stopPlugin();
        return false;   
        }

        $tempres .= $res;
        $cursorNext = $this->getElementDOM($res,'//users_list/next_cursor');

    }while(1);

    $contacts = $this->getElementDOM($tempres,'//screen_name');
    return $contacts;   
    }
```

By FRAG =)

Comment: can you please tell me where you got this code?

Comment: Awesome example thanks. Saved me heaps of time with my app

Answer (score 5):

When you call `$this->twitter->getFollowers();` you basically hitting the 100 followers per page limit. Try to make use of the paging to subsequentially access all your followers, if you happen to have more than 100 ...

See also: http://apiwiki.twitter.com/Twitter-REST-API-Method%3A-statuses%C2%A0followers

> **cursor**. Optional. Breaks the results into pages. A single
>   page contains 100 users. This is recommended for users who
>   are followed by many other users. Provide a value of -1 to
>   begin paging. Provide values as returned to in the response
>   body's next_cursor and previous_cursor attributes to page
>   back and forth in the list.
>
> Example: http://twitter.com/statuses/followers/barackobama.xml?cursor=-1
>
> Example: http://twitter.com/statuses/followers/barackobama.xml?cursor=1300794057949944903

Answer (score 2):

As others have mentioned, there's a limit of 100 users returned on that API call, and yes, you should be switching from page-based to cursor-based calls Real Soon Now.

To actually answer your question, though...check and see if the number of results returned is == 100, and if so, call `$this->twitter->getFollowers(null, $page);` where `$page` is a counter that you increment. If you get back < 100 results, that's the last page.

Comment: Checking to see if the number of results is 100 won't always work, the result set isn't guaranteed to be 100 every time as suspended users will be filtered out. http://apiwiki.twitter.com/Twitter-REST-API-Method:-statuses%C2%A0followers

Comment: Good point. I need to go tweak a script (or just go ahead and update it to cursors). I guess you could keep checking to see if the result set is empty, which should mean you've hit the last page.

Answer (score 1):

You should be using the twitter API so you can call http://twitter.com/followers/ids.format
That allows you to page the results using the cursor parameter. See the [page here](http://apiwiki.twitter.com/Twitter-REST-API-Method:-followers%C2%A0ids)

Answer (score 0):

If I see that right, you're accessing the URL `statuses/followers/[...].xml`. It seems that this is restricted to 100 users per page, to get additional pages and so more users, use the URLs `statuses/followers/[...].xml?page=N` with N >= 2.

As The MYYN and others stated, this isn't correct use anymore, and you should use `statuses/followers/[...].xml?cursor=-1` and similar.

Comment: from the twitter api docs: The previously documented page-based pagination mechanism is still in production, but will be deprecated. Please migrate to cursor-based pagination for increased reliability and performance.